# how to detect device rotation from SKscene

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I am just trying out the XCode's SpriteKit sample application and I am changing it to test and learn as I go along.

I want to find a Function which detect device rotation in the GameScene (SKScene subclass), i.e. this function should trigger when device is rotated from portrait to landscape etc.

I found a function

`override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)`

but this function works only in the GameViewController (UIViewController subclass). I need a similar function that exist in SKScene subclasses.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [didRotate(from:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621492-didrotate) is deprecated since iOS 8.0 so we are going to use the new method.

You'll need to tell your ´GameViewController to inform the current scene every time a rotation occurs.

### 1. The CanReceiveTransitionEvents protocol

Let's define a protocol to say that the conform type (our scene) can receive rotation events

```
protocol CanReceiveTransitionEvents {
    func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize)
}
```

### 2. Conforming our scene to CanReceiveRotationEvents

Now let's conform our own SKScene to the protocol

```
class GameScene: SKScene, CanReceiveTransitionEvents {

    func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize) {
        // this method will be called when a change in screen size occurs
        // so add here your code
    }
}
```

> If you have multiple scenes just repeat for each one.

### 3. The ViewController should inform the scene of each rotation

Finally lets make the controller to call the related scene method every time a rotation is detected

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    guard
        let skView = self.view as? SKView,
        let canReceiveRotationEvents = skView.scene as? CanReceiveTransitionEvents else { return }

    canReceiveRotationEvents.viewWillTransition(to: size)
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Your answer worked. At first I thought of using a delegate & protocol pattern but it did not work because I had problem referencing the GameViewController instance that was presenting the SKScene. My delegate was Nil. I did not know that I can use protocol like what you showed me (that is without creating a delegate variable). This is new to me. Where did you learn this? I want to give you a check mark or Upvote your answer but somehow StackOverflow does not allow me to do this. Thank you again!