# How to integrate UIDevice rotation and creating a new UIBezierPath after rotation?

Tags: uibezierpath

**How to integrate UIDevice rotation and creating a new UIBezierPath after rotation?**

My challenge here is to successfully integrate `UIDevice` rotation and creating a **new** `UIBezierPath` every time the `UIDevice` is rotated.

**EDIT:** changed to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` per DonMag's recommendation. This makes sense because I wish to generate a new UIBezierPath **after rotation** when all the SKSpriteNodes have been resized and repositioned.

Oh, how I wish that worked .. but it did **not**

As a preamble, I have bounced back and forth between

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(rotated),
                                           name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
                                           object: nil)
```

called within my `viewDidLoad()` together with

```
    @objc func rotated() {

    }
```

**and**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    // please see code below

}
```

My success was much better when I implemented `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, versus `rotated()` .. so let me provide detailed code just for  `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

I have concluded that every time I rotate the `UIDevice`, a **new** `UIBezierPath` needs to be generated because `positions` and `sizes` of my various `SKSprieNodes` change.

I am definitely **not** saying that I have to create a new `UIBezierPath` with every rotation .. just saying **I think** I have to.

**Start of Code**

```
// declared at the top of my `GameViewController`:
var myTrain: SKSpriteNode!
var savedTrainPosition: CGPoint?
var trackOffset = 60.0
var trackRect: CGRect!
var trainPath: UIBezierPath!
```

My `UIBezierPath` creation and `SKAction.follow` code is as follows:

```
// called with my setTrackPaths() – see way below
func createTrainPath() {
    
    // savedTrainPosition initially set within setTrackPaths().
    // We no longer keep tabs on this Position because
    // UIBezierPath's built-in .currentPoint does that for us.
    trackRect = CGRect(x: savedTrainPosition!.x,
                       y: savedTrainPosition!.y,
                       width: tracksWidth,
                       height: tracksHeight)
    trainPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: trackRect)
    trainPath = trainPath.reversing()   // makes myTrain move CW
                                    
}   // createTrainPath


func startFollowTrainPath() {
   
    let theSpeed = Double(5*thisSpeed)

    var trainAction = SKAction.follow(
                                  trainPath.cgPath,
                                  asOffset: false,
                                  orientToPath: true,
                                  speed: theSpeed)
    trainAction = SKAction.repeatForever(trainAction)
    createPivotNodeFor(myTrain)
    myTrain.run(trainAction, withKey: runTrainKey)

}   // startFollowTrainPath


func stopFollowTrainPath() {
    
    guard myTrain == nil else {
        myTrain.removeAction(forKey: runTrainKey)
        savedTrainPosition = myTrain.position
        return
    }
    
}   // stopFollowTrainPath
```

Here is the detailed `viewWillLayoutSubviews` I promised earlier:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    if (thisSceneName == "GameScene") {

        // code to pause moving game pieces

        setGamePieceParms()   // for GamePieces, e.g., trainWidth
        setTrackPaths()       // for trainPath
        reSizeAndPositionNodes()
            
        // code to resume moving game pieces

    }   // if (thisSceneName == "GameScene")
            
}   // viewDidLayoutSubviews


    func setGamePieceParms() {
        
        if (thisSceneName == "GameScene") {
        
            roomScale = 1.0
            let roomRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
            roomWidth    = roomRect.width
            roomHeight   = roomRect.height
            roomPosX = 0.0
            roomPosY = 0.0

            tracksScale = 1.0
            tracksWidth  = roomWidth - 4*trackOffset   // inset from screen edge
#if os(iOS)
            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
                tracksHeight = 0.30*roomHeight
            }
            else {
                tracksHeight = 0.38*roomHeight
            }
#endif
            // center horizontally
            tracksPosX = roomPosX
            // flush with bottom of UIScreen
            let temp = roomPosY - roomHeight/2
            tracksPosY = temp + trackOffset + tracksHeight/2

            trainScale = 2.8
            trainWidth  = 96.0*trainScale   // original size = 96 x 110
            trainHeight = 110.0*trainScale
            trainPosX = roomPosX
#if os(iOS)
            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
                trainPosY = temp + trackOffset + tracksHeight + 0.30*trainHeight
            }
            else {
                trainPosY = temp + trackOffset + tracksHeight + 0.20*trainHeight
            }
#endif

    }   // setGamePieceParms

// a work in progress
func setTrackPaths() {
   
    if (thisSceneName == "GameScene") {
        
        if (savedTrainPosition == nil) {                
            savedTrainPosition = CGPoint(x: tracksPosX - tracksWidth/2, y: tracksPosY)
        }
        else {
            savedTrainPosition = CGPoint(x: tracksPosX - tracksWidth/2, y: tracksPosY)
        }
        
        createTrainPath()

    }   // if (thisSceneName == "GameScene")

}   // setTrackPaths

func reSizeAndPositionNodes() {

    myTracks.size = CGSize(width: tracksWidth, height: tracksHeight)
    myTracks.position = CGPoint(x: tracksPosX, y: tracksPosY)

    // more Nodes here ..

}
```

**End of Code**

My theory says  when I call `setTrackPaths()` with every `UIDevice` rotation, `createTrainPath()` should be called.

Nothing happens of significance visually as far as the `UIBezierPath` is concerned .. until I call  `startFollowTrainPath()`.

**Bottom Line**

It is then that I see for sure that a new `UIBezierPath` has **not** been created as it should have been when I called `createTrainPath()` when I rotated the `UIDevice`.

The **new** `UIBezierPath` is not new, but the old one.

If you’ve made it this far through my long code, **the question is what do I need to do to make a new `UIBezierPath` that fits the resized and repositioned `SKSpriteNode`?**

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` happens ***before*** the new layout. `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` happens ***after*** the new layout. More likely, you want to implement `viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`.

Comment: Much of the docs on this method address "animation" .. so I guess I do not understand?

Comment: Try to reduce your current task to as simple as possible... You say: *"... a new `UIBezierPath` has **not** been created ..."* -- but you also say: *"The **new** `UIBezierPath` is not new, but the old one."* So, is `createTrainPath()` actually running? As you're debugging this, are you calculating the framing incorrectly? Or are the values not what you expect them to be?

Comment: After rotation, a **new** one has **not** been created. This is for certain **because** the `SKSpriteNode` follows the **old** one if it's moving **before** rotation. **However**, if I stop the movement before the rotation within `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and resume the movement after the rotation, a new `UIBezierPath` **is** created. **But** what I want is to replace the `UIBezierPath` **while** moving when rotation happens. If you scroll up my OP, you will see that my `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` calls `createTrainPath()` which  needs **?** to be called during this rotation.

Comment: FYI I have tried to effectively delete the old `UIBezierPath` by clearing all the `.cgPath [CGPoint]` before calling `setTrackPaths()` (instead of stopping the movement and then resuming). Please note that my `setTrackPaths()` calls `createTrainPath()`. Unfortunately, the old Path stuck around with its old `[CGPoint]` and was never replaced by `createTrainPath()` when the latter called `trainPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: trackRect)`

Comment: It just dawned on me that the problem could rest with my call to `trackRect = CGRect(x:, y:, width:tracksWidth, height:tracksHeight)`. I say that **because** with rotation, the width and height parts change. Never mind ... I just deleted that guess because my call to `setGamePieceParms()` occurs **before** `setTrackPaths()` .. and the former changes `tracksWidth` and `tracksHeight` Back to the drawing board ...

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50048115/6257435

Comment: TO: DonMag. You come across as darn smart and super patient. By any chance, do you work for Apple Developer Support?  Just asking.

Comment: Up till now, I have been concentrating on building a **new** `UIBezierPath` with rotation of the `UIDevice`. 

I came across a set of routines that make an existing `UIBezierPath` fit into a **new** `cgPath.boundingBox`. Going from portrait to landscape and back just changes this `boundingBox`. So, I will travel down that road for a bit and see where it leads me.

Comment: I really suggest that simplify things, so you can work on one task at a time and understand what goes on. Are you changing the GameScene *size* when you rotate the device? What do you have the `.scaleMode` set to? In your previous questions, you were asking about multiple-point paths... in this question, you're working with only an oval/ellipse? (no, I don't work for Apple)

Comment: `scaleMode = .resizeFill`. Just an oval with the `[CGPoint]` generated by Apple via calling`trackRect = CGRect(x: savedTrainPosition!.x, y: savedTrainPosition!.y, width: tracksWidth, height: tracksHeight)
        trainPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: trackRect)`

Comment: Still trying to learn about `CGAffineTransform` which Apple states can be used to squeeze or expand the `path.cgPath.boundingBox` that happens with rotation, versus creating a **new** `UIBezierPath` with each rotation. This `boundingBox` parm is **not** settable so I'm not sure how that will work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to boil this down to the basics to make it understandable...

When using `scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill`, we can implement `override func didChangeSize(_ oldSize: CGSize)` in the `SKScene` class. This will be called when the scene size changes, such as on device rotation.

So, for a very simple example that will look like this:

[image]

[image]

We can use this image (named "arrow2"):

[image]

and this example code...

---

**GameViewController class**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var scene: GameScene!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        if let skView = view as? SKView {
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
        
    }
    
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .all
    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
```

---

**GameScene class**

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    var spOval: SKShapeNode!
    var myTrain: SKSpriteNode!
    
    var trainPath: UIBezierPath!
    
    var currentSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        // ellipse frame will be set in updateFraming
        spOval = SKShapeNode(ellipseIn: .zero)
        spOval.lineWidth = 5
        spOval.strokeColor = .lightGray
        addChild(spOval)
        
        myTrain = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "arrow2")
        addChild(myTrain)
        
        updateFraming()
        startAnim()
        
    }
    
    override func didChangeSize(_ oldSize: CGSize) {
        if let v = self.view {
            // this can be called multiple times on device rotation,
            //  so we only want to update the framing and animation
            //  if the size has changed
            if currentSize != v.frame.size {
                currentSize = v.frame.size
                updateFraming()
                startAnim()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateFraming() {
        // self.view is optional, so safely unwrap
        guard let thisSKView = self.view else { return }
        
        let sz = thisSKView.frame.size
        
        // make the ellipse width equal to view width minus 120-points on each side
        let w: CGFloat = sz.width - 240.0
        
        // if view is wider than tall (landscape)
        //  set ellipse height to 30% of view height
        // else (portrait)
        //  set ellipse height to 38% of view height
        let h: CGFloat = sz.width > sz.height ? sz.height * 0.3 : sz.height * 0.38
        
        // center horizontally
        let x: CGFloat = (sz.width - w) * 0.5
        
        // put bottom of ellipse 40-points from bottom of view
        let y: CGFloat = 40.0
        
        let r: CGRect = .init(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
        
        // create the "path to follow"
        trainPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: r).reversing()
        
        // update the visible oval
        spOval.path = trainPath.cgPath
    }
    
    func startAnim() {
        
        var trainAction = SKAction.follow(
            trainPath.cgPath,
            asOffset: false,
            orientToPath: true,
            speed: 200.0)
        trainAction = SKAction.repeatForever(trainAction)
        myTrain.run(trainAction, withKey: "myKey")
        
    }
    
}
```

---

Here's a link to a full project: https://github.com/DonMag/SpriteKitRotation

---

Not entirely sure this will give you what you're going for, since you have a lot of code that is not clear... but hopefully it can at least get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Got a hopefully quick question = I've got my rotation code within `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. In theory or practice, is there any difference between this place and your `didChangeSize`?

Comment: @JohnLove - `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is sent to the controller **after** it has laid out its subviews. *Before that happens* `didChangeSize` is sent to the `SKScene`. From Apple's docs: *This method is intended to be overridden in a subclass. Typically, you use this method to adjust the positions of nodes in the scene.* Without knowing everything about your goal, you may want/need to do some things in `didChangeSize` and other things in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. You need to write the code, run it, and test it to see if you get the result you want.

Comment: Please be assured I have over and over again tested my code. @DonMag, you are the very 1st programmer that has introduced me to `didChangeSize`. Up until now `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has been my focus. From the bottom of my heart, I cannot possibly thank you enough for all your extraordinary patience and programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

This reply is to @DonMag and is not meant to be an answer.

Boy, have I learned a lot from you ...

At the risk of pushing your buttons, here is a pic of **your** output when I substitute your "arrow2" with my "train".

Give me a week or whatever to struggle by myself .. but here are a few pics to describe my problem:

```
    let theSpeed = Double(5*thisSpeed)

    var trainAction = SKAction.follow(
                                  trainPath.cgPath,
                                  asOffset: false,
                                  orientToPath: true,  // <==
                                  speed: theSpeed)
    trainAction = SKAction.repeatForever(trainAction)
```

which is due to the fact that my Train is **not** symmetrical, unlike your "arrow2".

[image]

Here is what I am looking for:

[image]

Good Grief - easy for 0-degrees, 90-degrees + 270-degrees. Just use your favorite graphics editor and start with an image 90-degrees CCW and Swift will magically rotate it 90-degrees CW before it starts moving your SKSpriteNode.

Whoops, **not so fast** => if we pre-rotate it CCW to counter Swift's CW rotation, then when I display a static Train upon initial start-up of the App, the Train is rotated CCW 90-degrees. I let touch-swiping to stop and re-start movement, so upon start-up the Train is not moving.

The biggee is what I have labelled 180-degrees Somehow I've got to figure out how to keep track of where we are along the ellipse path and adjust the graphic accordingly. For example, it would be nice when at 90-degrees to add a z-rotation of **minus** 45-degrees and when at 270-degrees to add a z-rotation of **plus** 45-degrees.

Answer (score 0):

my Credits SKScene - hopefully you like it

[image]